# Assign different ip address to different connection on ec2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012-r2

On my windows, there are 2 static public ip addresses are available.

ip1 : default ip2 : external

When I connect to domain.com:21 or domain.com:80, I would like the target server to see my ip2 only.

how can i set it up ?

are there any software that i can use for this.

Comment: Just point your "domain.com" A entry in your DNS server (or service) to the adress you'd like to connect to. No additional software needed.